# Where can I find an APP ID in Google Developers Console

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I can see Project ID, Client ID, API Key, but I cannot find APP ID that the guide below asked me to set in my manifest file.

[MIME Types in App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest)

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=1234567890" />
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.1234567890" />
```

Comment: Did you enter to console.developers.google.com and enable google drive API?

Answer (score 9):

I believe you need to use "Project number" for your APP_ID, which can be found on the Settings section in the Google Dev Console.

1. Navigate to https://console.developers.google.com
2. Then open the hamburger menu and select **IAM & Admin**
3. Then select **Settings**, and you'll see "Project number" on the right

Comment: That's so intuitive... Thanks

Comment: So it looks like it's just the number before the dash in your client id. No looking in the console necessary.

Answer (score 7):

From the Developer console:

1. Click All Applications
2. Click on the App name from the right side pane
3. At the top of the page, clicking the down arrow next to the App name shows the id e.g. com.mulikapesa.myshop

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Developer console
2. Click on certain app
3. On app page on top of the screen to left of "bell" icon click on "Info" icon("i" in circle).

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the applicationId in the build.gradle file within your project's code.

Sorry this isn't in the google play console, I had issues finding it there as well

Answer (score 0):

If you have just registered your new app in google developer console and think about using play game service, you will be able to find your app project id in the next page just after registering game service. I'm not very familiar with google play console but in my case this way solved me. I'm glad to help someone with this simple solution:)