# Google drive scope (drive or drive.file) to read files uploaded by users

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing a mobile app (in Flutter) that can read and write files in a specific folder in the user's Google Drive.

Users can also manually upload files to this folder and the app must have access to these files.

So far, I am using `drive.file` scope and did not manage to have access to the files that the user has uploaded manually.

Do I need to use `drive` scope?

Is there any way to use the [driver picker](https://developers.google.com/picker) in my app and grant full access to a folder?

I would prefer to use `drive.file` scope. ([The difference is that 'drive.file' only gives you permission to files that your app has created or the user has explicitly shared with your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403014/google-drive-api-scope-and-file-access-drive-vs-drive-files)). But I don't know how to explicitly share a folder with my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope allows you to give a per-file access to files which have been created or opened by your app. Therefore, if the files have been upload *manually* and not from your app, this scope won't give you the access you require.

As for sharing the files with your application, you might find useful the example listed [here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#example) in order to prompt a user to share the files wanted.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Authenticate Your Users](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth);
- [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#gdata).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use the picker inside my flutter app.

Comment: List of all the scopes : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Comment: Drive API scopes : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive

Comment: Another important link : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth?hl=en#scopes