# How do you create a Google API App that uses the drive.file to access only specifically requested files?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm writing a C# Desktop app that as part of its job is to add/edit cells in a pre-existing Google Sheet that user has created and supplies the URL of. During development I've used the far more open Sheets.Files and Drive.Files scopes that allow read/write access to everything everywhere.

I am now trying to use the Drive.File scope to restrict the apps access to only the specific Sheet file we will be interacting with. However I am seriously struggling to understand how to, as part of the auth flow, ask the user for access to write to the file.

Previously I was auth'ing with:

```
        public async Task AuthGoogleSheets(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(CredentialsFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                _googleCreds = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets },
                    "user",
                    cancellationToken,
                    new FileDataStore(AuthTokenFilePath));

                await _googleCreds.RefreshTokenAsync(cancellationToken);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets service.
            sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = _googleCreds,
                ApplicationName = "myappname",
            });
        }
```

I had hoped simply adding a `LoginHint` with the sheet URL would do the job but it hasn't helped. Do I need to use DriveService to send a permission request email? That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the Drive API, but if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403014 is correct, it's not a matter of you specifying particular files - it's that the scope basically gives you access to files created *by the same app*. So if the user has created the file themselves, I *suspect* the drive.file scope won't work.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet that has been my concern too. But I don't understand what scope Goog wants me to use then - They require manual verification for the full read/write scopes as they are restricted. Do I use _no_ scopes, but still need to request file access somehow.

Comment: Well it sounds like you either need manual verification, or to create the file yourself and maybe get the user to populate it.

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of verification the process is much more stream lined these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the docs. [Drive scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)

[image]

The `Drive.File` scope gives you access to files that where created by your application only.  For your app to have created it you must have used file.create and used an access token that was created by the client id you have for your app, directly into the users drive account.

All other scopes give you access to the users full drive account. For example `drive.readonly` will for example give you full read only access to all of the files on the users google drive account.

There is no way to limit it without using Drive.File.

You could use a service account and ask the user to share a folder on their drive account with the service account.  This can work but it depends upon your user base, and it will then be up to you to ensure that you know "which" user the folder belongs to. Doing this can lead to confusion and sharing data with the wrong user if your not careful but it depends on your use case.

Comment: I suppose my real question here is: How do I request access to a drive file for my app without using the restricted scopes Google clearly doesn't want us to use?

Comment: Well unless its a file that your app created you cant really.  Restricted scopes for drive are there to protect the user.   You will need to prove to Google that your app is secure.  Its doable.   If it is a file that was created by your app then just use drive.file

Comment: I guess to get to the meat of it: Google provides no way for me to request permission to a Google Sheet via the API? Can I not send a Permissions request for the app itself?

Comment: No permission is user + app based the user needs to consent to your app accessing their data this is done though Oauth2.   Again its an all or nothing thing.   Unless you can arrange for your app to create this file. Then you will need full access to the users drive account to access it.  Before you ask no you cant use like a share with me link this is not true sharing so your app wont have access.  You could ask the user to set the file public then you could access it via an api key, but then you wouldn't be able to write to the file.